# What should this projection be in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-server, coordinate-system

This is ESRI rest prj, "spatialReference":

> {"wkt": "GEOGCS[\"GCS_WGS_1984\",DATUM[\"WGS84\",SPHEROID[\"WGS84\",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]]"}

Does anybody know what it should be in OpenLayers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how ESRI specifies the Geographic Coordinate system in WGS 84 datum.

The EPSG code for this is [EPSG:4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/)

Comment: ,thanks for your reply,I also want to ask you another question,why when I drag my map,it quickly show on the contrary direction and sometimes the map do not even move?please,this issue has tortures me for a long time,thank you !

Comment: @ethelhao I have noticed several Questions arising out of a single issue and asking the same question multiple times does not fit well with the Q&A format of GIS Stack Exchange. My recommendation is that you [**take the tour**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/about) of how GIS Stack Exchange works